# Generar URL Amigable para búsqueda por GET en un formulario (PHP)

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, url

Tengo un pequeño inconveniente...
Desarrollo un pequeño CRUD con PHP puro, en el cuál trato de generar una URL Amigable por medio del `.htaccess` .

La URL Amigable es para realizar una búsqueda en un formulario. Deseo que la URL se vea de la siguiente forma:

De

```
misitioweb.com/buscar?b=jose
```

a

```
misitioweb.com/buscar/jose
```

Hasta ahora he logrado obtener el dato enviado por GET, pero no logro definir bien la estructura de la URL deseada. (Tengo una sección *template* que trae todo el contenido de la página de búsqueda `?content=buscar`).

HTML

```
<form method="GET" action="/panel-control-mysql/buscar">        
    <input type="search" id="buscar" placeholder="Escribe algo..." name="buscar" >
    <button type="submit">Buscar</button>
</form>
```

.htaccess

```
RewriteRule panel-control-mysql/buscar$ ?content=buscar [QSA]
RewriteRule panel-control-mysql/buscar/(\w+)  ?buscar=$1
```

Saludos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cuando envías formularios por método `GET` automáticamente se agregan datos en URL `?variable=valor`, tal vez pudieras manejar alguna redirección en `.htaccess`, algo como:

```
# Con botón submit en URL
RewriteRule ^/panel-control-mysql/buscar?buscar=(.*)&(.*)$ /panel-control-mysql/buscar/$1 [L,NC,R=301]
# Sin botón submit en URL
RewriteRule ^/panel-control-mysql/buscar?buscar=(.*)$ /panel-control-mysql/buscar/$1 [L,NC,R=301]
```

Explicación:

- El formulario tiene como acción la URL `/panel-control-mysql/buscar`
- Se va a agregar el campo `buscar` y, probablemente, el botón `submit` a la URL
- En la primera regla se captura con valor de `buscar`, que se toma después con `$1`, y botón `submit`, que se ignora. En la segunda no se consideran variables adicionales
- En ambos casos, se va a redirigir a la URL que deseas con `[L,NC,R=301]`

  - `L` Aplica la redirección
  - `NC` Es para no diferenciar mayúsculas y minúsculas, tal vez no sea necesario, pero tampoco afecta el rendimiento
  - `R=301` Es para enviar encabezado de redirección permanente, para que los motores de búsqueda no indexen la URL original con parámetros

Para saber más de las opciones del módulo Rewrite, visita la [documentación](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html).

Otra opción es capturar el evento `submit` del formulario en Javascript y desde ahí hacer las modificaciones necesarias:

```js
// Obtener formulario
let frmBusca = document.querySelector('#frm-buscar');
// Asignar evento
frmBusca.addEventListener('submit', e => {
     // Evitar envío de formulario
     e.preventDefault();
     // Obtener valor desde campo y eliminar espacios ' jose ' quedaria como 'jose'
     let busca = frmBusca.querySelector('input').value.trim();
     // Verificar que no esté vacío
     if(busca == '') {
         alert('Teclea algo para buscar');
         return;
     }
     // Cambiar a minúsculas y remplazar espacios con guiones
     // 'Jose Perez' quedaría como 'jose-perez'
     busca = busca.toLowerCase().replaceAll(' ', '-');
     // Crear la nueva URL:
     let url = '/panel-control-mysql/buscar/' + busca;
     // Puedes borrar la siguiente línea, es solo para ver que genera la URL correcta
     console.log(url);
     // Descomenta la siguente línea para ir a la página de búsqueda
     // location.href = url;
});
```

```html
<!-- Agrega ID al formulario para obtenerlo más fácilmente -->
<form method="GET" action="/panel-control-mysql/buscar" id="frm-buscar">        
    <input type="search" id="buscar" placeholder="Escribe algo..." name="buscar" >
    <button type="submit">Buscar</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta. En la primera parte de la respuesta, en el código del `RewriteRule`, las URLs no deberían estar al revés? Para que el resultado final fuera `misitioweb.com/buscar/jose`. O crees que se tendría que cambiar la URL del Action del formulario?

Comment: A que te refieres con _Con o Sin botón submit en URL_ ?

Comment: Sigo sin tener el resultado esperado, sea como sea sigo recibiendo en la URL `?buscar=valor`

Comment: Probé con el script de Javascript (generando la URL y redireccionándolo), e ingresando esto en el .htaccess `RewriteRule panel-control-mysql/buscar/(\w+) ?content=buscar?buscar=$1`, y nada.

Comment: Las URLs enviadas por GET obtienen el name y los valores de los INPUT, no de los botones SUBMIT... O estoy equivocado?

Comment: Otra duda... en la sintaxis de la regla `RewriteRule` del `.htaccess`, en primer lugar (osea , luego del `RewriteRule`) se pone la URL "falsa" a aparecer en la barra de direcciones, y luego de eso, separado por un espacio, la URL original y existente? Por lo que en la sugerencia que comentaste, al tratar de seguir esa estructura, no me funciona, ya que me parece que no respeta la regla sintáctica: `RewriteRule panel-control-mysql/buscar?buscar=(.*)&(.*) /panel-control-mysql/buscar/$1` Corrígeme si estoy equivocado porfavor.

Comment: @EDG_DGK, cierto, faltaba un `$` después del último paréntesis para especificar final de cadena. En cuanto a los botones, también son campos de formulario y podrían ser enviados como parámetros, pero puedes omitir esa parte, si lo deseas.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, y sobre la consulta de la sintáxis del `RewriteRule` ?

Comment: @EDG_DGK, se pone primero la URL REAL, es decir, la que crea el formulario al enviarse y, después, la que quieres que se muestre en el navegador. Las reglas que tienes después son las que se encargan de hacer que todo funcione como esperas. Una pregunta... ¿Ya lo probaste?

Comment: Revisando el código de JavaScript y la estructura de mi proyecto, logré solucionar el problema. Muchas gracias por la respuesta. Una última consulta, sé que esto es algo que debo investigarlo por mi cuenta pero quiero aprovechar ahora que se aplicó en este caso... ¿Por qué se utilizó `querySelector` en lugar de `document.getElementById` en el código JavaScript ?

Comment: @EDG_DGK, funcionan igual, pero me gusta más `querySelector()` porque te permite usar selectores CSS como los declaras en hojas de estilo y, además, son menos mayúsculas para escribir.